# How to use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier in Swift?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

If I uncomment

```
tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?)
```

I get an error on the line

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)
```

that says `UITableView? does not have a member named 'dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier'`

If I unwrap the tableview then the error goes away, but in Objective-C we would normally check whether or not the cell exists, and if it does not we create a new one.  In Swift, since the boilerplate provided uses the `let` keyword and unwraps an optional, we can't reassign it if it's nil.

What's the proper way to use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier in Swift?

Comment: regarding the cell could be nil. no not with this method. docs: " UITableViewCell object with the associated reuse identifier. This method always returns a valid cell"

Comment: The confused me also because I remember the ObjC days where you checked for nil in case there was no cell to reuse, and if nil created a new cell with the `reuseIdentifier`. I read the current Apple doc again and it says "This method dequeues an existing cell if one is available or creates a new one using the class or nib file you previously registered." So, the function does both for us now, which is nice. See this discussion though, there are 2 dequeue calls--one returns optional, the other not: [link](https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-using-the-wrong-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier/)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can implicitly unwrap the parameters to the method and also cast the result of  `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` to give the following succinct code:

```
func tableView(
    _ tableView: UITableView,
    cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath
) -> UITableViewCell {
    let reuseIdentifier = String(describing: MyCustomCell.self)
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    precondition(cell is MyCustomCell,
                 "Dequeued cell is not of MyCustomCell type")
    if let myCustomCell = cell as? MyCustomCell {
        // Configure myCustomCell
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: This is the answer I can up with as well - the major difference being the use of `!` (for implicitly unwrapped optional) instead of `?` in the function definition (just pointing it out for those who don't immediately notice the difference). I also think the boilerplate provided by Apple in XCode 6 will replace their definition with this one as well.

Answer (score 28):

If the cell type hasn't been registered with the table view before the table loads, you can use the following to fetch a cell instance:

```
private let cellReuseIdentifier: String = "yourCellReuseIdentifier"

// MARK: UITableViewDataSource

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  var cell:UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellReuseIdentifier)
  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier:cellReuseIdentifier)
  }
  cell!.textLabel!.text = "Hello World"
  return cell!
}
```

Comment: Gives warning in swift 2.0: `Conditional cast from 'UITableViewCell' to 'UITableViewCell' always succeeds`

Comment: Just need to remove the `as?`

Comment: Yes, and I think the if statement `if (cell == nil) {`... also should be removed. It gives an error as cell is not of optional type.

Comment: Hm, from the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier doc, the returned value is optional...  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:

Comment: My bad. I was using [dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:) which according to the docs always returns a valid cell in Swift 2.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why we do: `    cell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier:cellReuseIdentifier)
` with this approach of yours...do we even have to do `tableView.registerClass`...?! Or that's no longer needed?! If it's still needed, can you explain why?

Answer (score 5):

You do need to unwrap the tableView variable as it is an optional

```
if let realTableView = tableView {
    let cell = realTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    // etc
} else {
    // tableView was nil
}
```

or you can shorten it by

```
tableView?.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)
```

In answer to your question about 'in Objective-C we would normally check whether or not the cell exists, and if it does not we create a new one', `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` always returns a cell (so long as you've registered a class or a nib for this identifier), so you don't need to create a new one.

Comment: dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier does not always return a cell, cf documentation

Comment: Sorry, I meant always returns a cell if you've set it up correctly. I've edited it to be clearer

Comment: If you use this approach in cellForAtIndexPath, how do you return cell?

Answer (score 5):

**In Swift 3 and Swift 4 Version you just use this**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellIdentifier", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = "cell number \(indexPath.row)."

        //cell code here

        return cell
    }
```

**In Swift 2 Version**

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

 cell.textLabel?.text = "cell number \(indexPath.row)."

        //cell code here

        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

swift 3 version:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"CellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
      return cell
    }
```