# Setting delegate and datasource in custom UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, subclass

I'm trying to create a `UITableView` as a custom subview of my `UIViewController`, however the data is not showing up in the table. I suspect that the problem is my `delegate` and `datasource` for the table are not set. How can I link them? The `UITableViewDataSource` doesn't seem to work within a `UITableView` class?

**UIViewController**

```
    let projectDeck = ProjectDeck()
    projectDeck.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: statusBarHeight + 132, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight - 132)
    self.view.addSubview(projectDeck)
```

**UITableView**

```
class ProjectDeck: UITableView {

    var items = ["Test", "TestTest", "TestBestWestVest"]

    override func numberOfRows(inSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    override func cellForRow(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell? {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: projectDeck.delegate = self , same with datasource (if your UIViewController is the delegate or datasource) , **Remember** that you need to provide a correct height for your tableView Cells . https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [set delegate and datasource of uitableview programmatically in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022136/set-delegate-and-datasource-of-uitableview-programmatically-in-swift)

Comment: How to dequeue cells: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471954/how-to-use-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-in-swift

Answer (score 1):

You need to add datasource and delegate reference.

You can do it by taking outlet or from the storyboard.

**Using Outlets:**

```
yourTableView.datasource = self
yourTableView. delegate = self
```

**Using StoryBoard**

ctrl-drag table view to viewcontroller next to first responder and click datasource and delegate.

Answer (score 0):

set delegate and datasource in your viewcontrloller

i.e. in viewcontroller

```
projectdesc.tableview.datasource = self
projectdesc.tableview.delegate = self
```

and implements methods of tableview like cellforRow in viewccontroller

and be sure you are adding tableview as a subview in viewcontroller properly